# Understanding of JSON array iteration in TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

I would like to understand what I did wrongly. I have tried to read this, but it was overwhelmingly detailed:
[Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

```
{
    "dogs":[
         {
             "name": "shiba",
             ....
         }
         {
             "name": "akita",
             ....
         }
      ]
 }
```

I read the JSON from an HTTP server and it was returned as `data`.

```
       for(var item in data["dogs"])
       {
         console.log(item["name"]);
         console.log(data["dogs"][0]["name"]);
       }
```

`console.log(item["name"]);` does not work, returning 'undefined'. `console.log(data["dogs"][0]["name"]);` works, but since it has a fixed index, it does not iterate all names. Why isn't the first one working?

In VS Code, if I set a breakpoint at that line, somehow the breakpoint does not stay. It gets hit but continues away in a second, so I cannot examine the data. Before running, if I place the mouse on `item`, the popup says that the type is `string`. Why is it a string; shouldn't it be 'any'?

Comment: JS's `for...in` doesn't do what it looks like it should do. It iterates the keys of an object, not the elements of an array. If you use `for (let item of data["dogs"])` (note `of` instead of `in`) it should work, as long as you're targeting ES6 or above. (Below ES6, you'll have to use a helper function such as `$.each`.)

Comment: Thank you. I changed 'in' to 'of', and it worked as I intended. So, 'in' is for keys, 'of' is for values.